# Ошибка с пространством имён

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

Я написал большой скрипт используя `System.Numerics`, ошибок в коде не было, Visual Studio его нормально воспринимал. Захожу в Unity, а там, у каждого использующего это пространство имён, ошибка:

> The type or namespace name Numerics does not exist in the namespace
>   System. Are you missing System.Numerics assembly reference?

В Studon references всё указано. Если я перезахожу в проект галочки в reference пропадают.

Что с этим можно сделать?

---

Unity 2017.3.0f3

Проект на *.net 4.6*

Comment: Какого запрета? Вы ошибку прочитали? Правильно ли прочитали ее?

Comment: @Yami Прочитал... Ну а делать то что? Unity 2017.3.0f3

Comment: Данная библиотека поддерживается `Mono`?

Comment: @Yami Вы предлагаете обновить mono для поддержки net 4.0?

Comment: Нет, перейдите в директорию юнити, там найдете папку `mono`, скопируйте туда библиотеку из папки `.net`, после чего попробуйте запустить снова. Mono не использует библиотеки `.net` установленной на `Windows`.

Comment: @Yami Огромное спасибо. Сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если переключение версии фреймворка не помогло. Ещё одна из идей - создать отдельный проект, инкапсулировать и вынести туда всё, что использует System.Numerics, после чего скомпилировать .dll файл и поместить его в ваш проект.
Я, например, таким образом использую возможности из C# 7.1, хотя, Unity использует более низкую версию.

Comment: Проблема в том, что большинство скриптов используют System.Numerics и они тесно связаны с неиспользующими. Есть вариант при котором не используется данный неймспейс, но он предполагает изобретение большого велосипеда. Это на крайний случай.

Comment: @Andrew, хм, а что если все эти вызовы сделать через прокси-утилиту, а саму утилиту собрать в dll-ку? Мол классы обращаются не напрямую к методам Numerics, а через утилиту из dll? Ну, и прежде чем извращаться, можно попробовать закрыть проект, удалить папку Library, .vs, все файлы .csproj и файл .sln и папку Temp, если она вдруг останется. После чего снова открыть и проверить.

Comment: Спасибо, приду домой, тогда попробую.