# Запутанность фреймворков

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

Начал бороться с тем, что *Unity* отказывается видеть `System.Numerics`. Сделал всё как мне [посоветовали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/818991/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-unity). В папке *mono* в версии *.net 4.0* нужное пространство имён есть. Далее, исследуя проблему, я наткнулся на то, что у меня всь код в *.net 3.5*:

[image: a]

При смене на *.net 4.0* оно вроде как меняется, код в *Visual Studio* перестаёт святиться красным, но *Unity* всё ещё ругается. При перезаходе всё откатывается.

Вопрос: Как изменить *.NET framework* на котором работает проект *Unity* с *3.5* на *4.0*?

Всё что может понадобится:

> Unity 2017.3.0f3
>
> Ошибка в Unity: The type or namespace name Numerics does not exist in the namespace System. Are you missing System.Numerics assembly reference?

---

[Немного больше информации если пригодиться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/818991/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-unity)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File -> Build Settings -> Player Settings -> Other Settings -> Scripting Runtime Version -> выбрать Experimental (NET 4.6).
Таким образом вы смените версию фреймворка, которую использует Unity.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Как на Stackoverflow можно отблагодарить человека?

Comment: @Andrew, ну, вы это уже сделали - сказали спасибо и отметили ответ верным)

Comment: Проблемы продолжаются! Я сделал всё как вы сказали и да, версия  фреймворка поменялась, но при включении галочки в reference описанная ошибка не уходит, а при перезаходе галочка снимается.